# LocationRelativeTo (JAVA) is Failing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I often use:

```
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

In my JFrame Constructor to make the Frame appear right in the middle, but now it doesnt works. It just puts the JFrame in one corner.

If you have any idea of what this happens or if you now another way to always making the Jframe appear at the middle in any computer please tell me.

I said this because I could use

```
setLocation(x,y);
```

and just put the coordinates that will put the Jframe in the center of my screen but, for example if my PC is 1920 x 1080 the Jframe wont appear in the center in a 1280 x 720 PC.

If Im wrong in this please correct me, Im new to Java so I can miss a lot of things Bill Gates wont miss. (I now windows is not coded in Java)

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, here's an example that works correctly; you might compare it to your current approach. In particular,

- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Be sure to `pack()` the enclosing [top-level container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).
- Invoke `setVisible(true)` as the *last* step in creating the GUI.

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29643591/230513 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JLabel("Test", JLabel.CENTER));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                new Test().display();
        });
    }
}
```